# Replace fragment in viewpager is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter, fragmentmanager

In my project i am using actionbar with swipeable threefragments(tabs with viewpager), i am trying to replace one of the fragment with fourth fragment, but iam not able to get it..

```
**Below is my code**

    public class GetRideFragment extends Fragment implements ICustomDateTimeListener, SelectedLocationListener{

        public GetRideFragment() {
        }
        @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


           }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_getride, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }


        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            fromac.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    /* Intent newintent = new Intent(getActivity(), AutoSearchActivity.class);
                     startActivity(newintent);
                     getActivity().overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );*/

                    PlaceSearchFragment fh = new PlaceSearchFragment();
                     FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                     FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                     ft.replace(R.id.fragcontainer, fh);
                     ft.addToBackStack("fh");
                     ft.commit();

                }
            });
```

**Below is my layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/fragcontainer">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragcontainer"
     >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ridetitile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get a Ride"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:background="@drawable/gray_btn_disabled_normal" >
...............
...........
```

**My adpater**

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new GetRideFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new PostRideFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new SearchRidesFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

nNot sure where i am going wrong.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the problem should be in the adapter. which one are u using?

Comment: any error??? if then show your logcat

Comment: @carlo.marinangeli iam using FragmentStatePagerAdapter...update my question with adapter pls take a look

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found the solution after a lot of searches. I would see 2 problems in your code: (sorry for my bad english)

1) to change an item inside the adapter (connected to your viewpager) for a given position, you have to change the items returned by the method `public Fragment getItem(int index)` and  call the method `notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify to the adapter that the content is changed.

2) the implementation of the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` contains a cache based on the position and it doesn't change even if you call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` and you return the `PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE` (there is an issue reported here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37990)

what I would suggest you is:

- use a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, implement properly the methods `getItem(int index)` (with the correct item at the given position), `getItemPosition(Object object)`, and `getItemId(int position)`
- if you want to use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, consider the implementation suggested in the issue I liked above ([NewFragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=37990&aid=379900000001&name=NewFragmentStatePagerAdapter.java)).

I hope it helps!

Comment: Iam doing as @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int index) {

  switch (index) {
  case 0:

            if(index == 0) {
                return GetRideFragment.newInstance();
            } else {
            
                return PlaceSearchFragment.newInstance();
               }
  i can see the new fragment on top, but old fragment still stay...can u please tell where i should use    notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: every time you want to change a content inside an adapter (or better: every time the content changes and so the `getItem` is ready to return different fragments -> you replace a fragment), you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. in this way you notify the adapter that it has to refresh.